# need to retrieve a database row value via sql based on values retrieved via previous sql query in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My code goes something like this

```
DataBaseUtil dbBaseUtil=new DataBaseUtil();
Connection con=dbBaseUtil.getConnection();

String query="select case_id, ticket_id from VAPP_ITEM where
(person1_alt_email='" + username +"') and ticket_type='Service Request' and       ticket_status not in ('Closed','Resolved')";

ResultSet rs=dbBaseUtil.getDbResultSet(query);
List<String> tickets=new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next())
ticket.add(rs.getString("case_Id")+"-"+rs.getString("ticket_Id"));

MyTicketUtil.searchAndOpenTicket(webui, "", tickets.get(0));
```

Now, once I get the element "tickets(0)", I perform some operations on it, and after the operations are performed, I need to retrieve ticket_status for the ticket on which the operations were performed - tickets(0).

However, to query the database, I need case_id and ticket_id for tickets(0). How can it be done?

I tried creating two ResultSets and a query post operations like below:

```
while(rs1.next())
quer1 = "select ticket_status from VAPP_ITEM where case_id=rs.getString(1) and ticket_id = rs.getString(2)";
```

But this is not working - console shows below error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find either column "rs" or the user-defined function or aggregate "rs.getString", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You have included `rs.getString()` into string literal.

You should use `PreparedStatement` for such things:

```
quer1 = "SELECT ticket_status FROM vapp_item WHERE case_id=? AND ticket_id = ?";
PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(quer1);
while (rs1.next())
    {
    pstm.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
    pstm.setString(2, rs.getString(2));
    rs2 = pstm.executeQuery();
    ...
    }
```